# How to convert html tree in to a customized json tree using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
<ul id='parent_of_all'>
<li>
  <span class='operator'>&&</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class='operator'>||</span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class='operator'>&&</span>
          <ul>
            <li>
            <span class='condition'>1 == 1</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class='condition'>1 != 0</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
{"&&":[{'||':[ {'&&':[ {"lhs": "1", "comparator": "==", "rhs":"1"} ]} ] } , {"lhs": "1", "comparator": "!=", "rhs":"0"}]}
```

As of now, I know the basics of jQuery, JavaScript. I need to know where to start thinking in order to accomplish the above conversion.

And the html tree could be more complex with more children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Alexandru and @Nenad for giving a start. I have been able to complete this on my own.
Below is the function that generates json.

```
function prepare_json(current_node){
    var object = {}
    var span = $(current_node).children('span')
    if (span.hasClass('condition')){
        var text = span.html().split(" ");
        object = {lhs: text[0], comparator: text[1], rhs: text[2]}
    }
    else if(span.hasClass('operator')){
        var operator = span.text()
        object[operator] = (object[operator] || [])
        var children = $(current_node).children('ul').children('li')
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
            var child_pql = prepare_json([children[i]])
            object[operator].push(child_pql)
        }
    }
    return object
}
```

Below is the code that calls that function:

```
var parent_node = $('#parent_of_all').children('li')
var json = JSON.stringify(prepare_pql_json(parent_node), null, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a way to select the first level of `li`, I assumed you have a parent element with an id such as `list`. I wrote the following code using basic jquery so you can understand it.

```
var result = {};

var $all_li = $('#list').children('li');     // selecting the first level of li
for(var i in $all_li){                       // iterating all_li using for (you may use forEach )  

    var $current_li = $( $all_li[i] );                       // getting operator from first span
    var operator = $current_li.children('span').html();      // the text of the operator

    var $inner_spans = $current_li.find('>ul >li >span');    // getting list of children spans (from path $list>li>ul>li>span)
    var li_spans = [];                                       // an array where we will put the inner span objects
    for(var j in $inner_spans){ // iterating the inner spans
        var text = $($inner_spans[j]).html().split(" ");     // splitting the html
        li_spans.push({
            lhs: text[0],
            comparator: text[1],
            rhs: text[2]
        });                                // adding the splitted html to an object. Note: error if text didn't have 2 white spaces
    }

    result[operator] = li_spans;          // adding the operator key and li_spans value to the result json
}
```

This code will parse the html and construct the `result` json, it should work for the html format you provided. Keep in mind that it does not handle errors (such as bad tree format).
 simmiar html formats.

Comment: Thanks for giving a start. But your implementation is limited to one level of tree. So if i add a child at nth level, your code appends to the root parent but not immediate parent.

Comment: @bill_cosby You gave a very specific html structure and from your example we can't understant how the result should look like.

Comment: Sorry about that. But I did mention that the tree could be complex. I just made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `each` and `map`

```js
var obj = {}
var span = $('li > span').not('ul li span').text();

$('ul li span').each(function() {
 var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
 obj[span] = (obj[span]||[]).concat({lhs: text[0], comparator: text[1], rhs: text[2]});
});

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <span>&&</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>1 == 1</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>1 != 0</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: your implementation is same as Alexandru's and is limited to one level of tree. So if i add a child at nth level, your code appends to the root parent but not immediate parent